# Two part Form with Formik

Tags: reactjs, antd, formik

I want to create a page with two parts, one the input part which includes input fields using Formik and another part a Table (for example antd Table component) which shows the data inserted in part one.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a wrapper component above the Form and Table Component . 
Maintain the state in the wrapper . Now once you fill the details in the form pass the created form values as a callback to wrapper to update the state . 
Use that state to populate the data in the Table Component .

Here is the codeSandbox with an example

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-morning-1hb9v?fontsize=14